# Where does zombienet store the chainstate?

Tags: zombienet

I've not tried out zombienet but just going over the network definition file, I do not see a parameter to specify the chainstate path like we would with `--base-path /path/to/chain`. Is there an option to do just that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zombienet` was build with the goal of spawn and test ephemeral networks and with that purpose it will create an use a new directory in your `/tmp` directory for each network that you spawn by default (in native provider). But if you want to control where zombienet store all the artifacts (chainstate, logs, etc) you can use the flag  `-d, --dir <path>` to specify a directory to use.

Also, when you use `zombienet` in the native provider the `tmp` directory used to store all the artifacts will be displayed in the output.

Thanks!